# Looking for a specific nomad multipurpose keyboard

Tags: gaming, keyboards

I would like a very specific keyboard that seem surprisingly hard to find.

I could probably achieve this by having 2 different keyboards but I really don't want to carry 2 around.

My uses are :

- General (surfing, medias)
- Programming
- Gaming

#### Must haves:

- Compact (easy to carry around)
- Clearly separated media keys (play/pause, stop, next, previous, mute, and volume control). **standalone** so not requiring to press another **fn** key to activate.
- Clearly separated function keys: so some space between ESC and F1, between F4 and F5 and so forth
- Arrow keys
- Lights to see the keys in the dim light or dark.
- Wireless with proper encryption (so I guess a bluetooth one that does not keep disconnecting or a properly secured bundle)

##### Should have:

- Multiple layouts available (will use the local on which is **not** QWERTY)
- Trackpad
- **not** mechanical or at least not noisy
- If bluetooth, does not keep disconnecting after a certain time of inactivity

#### Not important:

- Numeric keypad. That is, I even prefer not to have one because it saves space, but I won't dismiss options that do have one.
- Programmable keys.
- Scroll-lock key.

For some reasons it is surprisingly hard to find such a keyboard. Althrough I have no doubts it can exists in theory.

### The best match I could find so far were :

Rii K18 Plus Wireless 3-LED Color Backlit (edit: deleted link to suspicious seller)

Missing:

- No reported wireless encryption
- Basic separated multimedia keys but no volume control !!?

Anne Pro Bluetooth 4.0
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B06XW87X9D](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XW87X9D)

Missing:

- No separated multimedia keys
- No separated function keys
- No trackpad

Answer (score 0):

Forget that top site, that looks like a scam. Also trackpads are rare on keyboards except laptop stuff. The bottem link is a mechanical keyboard, those can be pretty loud.

If you want a quiet keyboard, the Corsair K57 Wireless and Sharkoon Skiller SGK5 are good options. Both are cheap, have standalone media keys, are not so loud, have rgb and the sharkoon can connect to the pc without any interception (wired usb). They are not so small though, but I never had problems with the size of the sharkoon and the Corsair is about the same size. The function keys are in groups of four, and the escape is right on the left of those groups.

Hope this helped

Comment: Deleted the link that looks like a scam. Althrough the model actual exists and can be found on amazon.

Comment: The both keyboards you mention are therefore not wireless and not compact.

Comment: The corsair is wireless, but idd, those are not so compact

Answer (score 0):

I finally found some pretty relevant results :

Logitech G G915 - TKL, Non mechanical variant

- Expensive (200 €)
- No evidence of proper encryption with the "RF" mode. But also features bluetooth mode which I consider to be at least marginally secured.
- No really compact, but is thin and still less wide than a regular keyboard
- No touchpad